# The future of Microsoft Web services

Tags: web-services

I've just recently watched a couple of videos about Microsoft Web Services. The videos were old and when I searched the web I don't see much about this technology that's recent.

Can someone out there explain in just a few lines if this technology has been replaced by another technology and if not then what's really the purpose of the technology.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2):

Web services have been superseded by [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx).

You can find some comparisons [here](http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/10/17/wcf-vs-asmx-webservices.aspx) and [here](http://www.techbubbles.com/wcf/wcf-vs-aspnet-web-services/).

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/) and Java Web Services Developer Pack were some alternatives to Microsoft Web Services. You can follow-up on those as well to learn more on Web Services.